# Numbering that auto-changes throughout the document?

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I would like to number example sentences throughout my document (long document). Right now I use enumerate for this. I don't want the default way of numbering, though, but this one: (1), (2), etc.

I want this numbering to change by itself, in case I add an example in the middle of the text later on.

How can I do this? Should I put the whole document within the  `\begin{enumerate}[(1)]` and `\end{enumerate}` commands? If I do this, the whole document text is indented, but maybe I can change this?

If I put each example sentence in its own `\begin{enumerate}[(1)]` / `\end{enumerate}`, the numbering does not change by itself, and I don't want to have to do it manually.

I'm sure this is easy to solve, but I can't find the answer.  Thank you!

EDIT:

I would not only like to have example sentences in this on-going numbering, but also tables.

I'm not sure if it was a good idea to use tables here. I still wanted numbered example sentences, but with a direct translation underneath, and aligned in a nice way (a lot of scientific papers do it like this).

I'm adding an example from a paper that has the 'tabular' example sentence style I'd like to have.

[image]

Comment: Do you want every sentence numbered? Every paragraph? Just ones you specify? Please edit your question to include a complete compilable example showing what you want. Hard code the numbers you want automated.

Comment: I think, you should rather use the `enumitem` package and its `resume' feature for the continuation

Comment: Welcome! Take a look at `enumitem`.

Comment: Thanks, Christian! Using the `enumitem`with `shortlabels` worked! I have a follow-up question, which I will put in my edited first post ;)

Comment: @reenah: I don't see why you use `shortlabels` there. And please don't use portions of my answer in your post as well, neither it is very well to add a follow-up question in the same post :-( -- Since your question is solved, as you stated explicitly in your edit, consider to accept my answer

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I'm sorry I didn't accept your answer before. Done now. I suppose I will ask my follow-up question in another thread then. I'm also sorry for using parts of your answer, I only wanted to illustrate my follow-up question, since I had solved the first part with your answer. I used `shortlabels`because `enumitem` did not work with the `enumerate`package otherwise. I know I'm using a dated version of Latex probably, but I don't want to change while I'm in the middle of my current project. As you can see, I have hardly much knowledge of the version I'm using now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proposition with `enumitem` and its `resume` feature. One could define a specialized list for this as well, but I omitted this for shortness right now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{label={(\arabic*)},resume}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item An important sentence
\item Another important sentence
\end{enumerate}

\blindtext[2]

\begin{enumerate}
\item More important sentences
\item Even more important sentences
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

[image]